# simple way to get id of each item in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored proceudre like this:

```
alter procedure [dbo].[PDTCarDetails]
@carid nvarchar(100)=null,
@plateSource nvarchar(100)=null,
@platecode nvarchar(100)=null,
@plateNumber nvarchar(100)=null,
@parkingType nvarchar(100)=null,
@amount integer=null,
@driverId nvarchar(100)=null,
@cmpl bit=null,
@self bit=null,
@cmplname nvarchar(100)=null,
@remarks nvarchar(100)=null,
@make nvarchar(100)=null,
@model nvarchar(100)=null,
@color nvarchar(100)=null,
@carlocation nvarchar(100)=null,
@comments nvarchar(100)=null

as 
begin
SET NOCOUNT ON;
declare @Psid integer,@pcDid integer,@vtype integer,@cmplid integer,@mkid integer,@mdlid integer,
@clrid integer
select @psid= ps.PSID from PlateSource_tbl ps where ps.PS=@plateSource
select @pcDid= pc.PCdID from  PlateCode_tbl pc where pc.PlateCode=@platecode
select @vtype= v.vtid from VType_tbl v where v.Vtype=@parkingType
select @cmplid= c.CmplID from Complimentary_tbl c where c.CompName=@cmplname
select @mkid= m.mkid from  Make_tbl m where m.Make=@make
select @mdlid= md.mdlid from Model_tbl md where md.Model=@model
select @clrid= cl.colid from Color_tbl cl where cl.Colname=@color
end
```

first i am taking each value after that i am taking particular id of each value
is there any way to do this same thing with shorter than this stored procedure(i mean any other simple way to get particular id of each item in my stored procedure)

Comment: Because those tables appear to be unrelated, I don't think there is much else you can do. It doesn't look all that bad to me. You could use CTE or derived tables, but while clever, I would say its overkill and impacts readability. However, for performance, I might question whether all those tables need to be queried each time the SP is called. Maybe you split it up into smaller SP and let the client choose the best fit. Or you could check the args and avoid doing selects on the NULL cases as that is wasteful.

Comment: so..i need to re-write without using null